# is it possible to use the ui of xtext for some external .exe instead of defining grammar

Tags: java, xtext, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to use the UI of xtext (java plugin) for some external exe program using processbuilding

is it possible to change the functionality of compilation button so it do its work in routine manner and display the results of external .exe program .

Regards

Comment: Hi Andrew, would you be able to include more details on what you have tried so far to achieve this, and the specific problems that prevented you from doing this?

Comment: I have an exe compiler program to some language .
Xtext is something to define all grammar rules and then compile them
But am trying to use Xtext's GUI only with my compiler and want to make it work by displaying the results from my exe program 
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create an Eclipse RCP application with the xText plugins. Here is a link on how to create an Eclipse 4 RCP application: http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html.

Comment: When I used xtext some years ago it produced Eclipse plugins that could be used for an RCP application. But I don't know any more details right now.

Comment: class useGobbler {
        public static void main ( String args[] )
        {
        ProcessBuilder pb; 
        Process p;
        Reader r;
        StringBuilder sb;
        int ch;

        sb = new StringBuilder(2000);
        try
        {  
    pb = new ProcessBuilder("myexe","-v","test.exe", "test.lps");
   //File log = new File("log");
           pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
 //pb.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.appendTo(log));
  p = pb.start();

here is a lil chunk of code to run exe in which file of xtext editor i have to make changes to run my exe compiler .

Comment: above is a lil code to run  exe

here is a lil chunk of code to run exe in which file of xtext editor i have to make changes to run my exe compiler .

Comment: I was assuming that you don't want to run the xtext editor in Eclipse but you want the result of your xtext project - the generated plugins with the editors of your grammar in an own branded application. Such an application could be an Eclipse RCP application that can run in different operating systems. That includes MS Windows. 
Now it looks like you would like to create your own compiler and reuse xtext functionality in a legacy application. In this case I'm sorry as I can't help you to do that.

Comment: i want to know that is it some how possible that i just get the running GUI of eclips or Xtext so i can attach it with my compiler exe

i just want to save time in making fine GUI of editor 

Regards